# mysql doesnt return proper json

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I use mysql 5.7

I want to concatenate result from joined tables into single column. I use `JSON_OBJECT` function wrapped in `GROUP_CONCAT` function. here's query

```
SELECT r.id, r.name,
GROUP_CONCAT(
    JSON_OBJECT(
       'id', i.id, 'name', i.name, 'metrics', i.metrics, 'amount', ir.amount,
                  'cat_id', i.cat_id, 'cat_name', ic.name
    )) AS ingredients
FROM recipes r, ingredient_recipe_meta ir, ingredients i, ingredient_category ic
WHERE r.id = ir.recipe_id
AND i.id = ir.ingredient_id
AND i.cat_id = ic.id
GROUP BY r.id
LIMIT 1
```

column `ingredients` contains data from joined tables. the data retrieved correctly, but the problem is `ingredients` column did not convert to proper JSON.
[image: princsreen]
as you see it's kinda 'cut' at the end.

I also tried `JSON_ARRAY`, but now it doesn't convert to proper array. its seems like, the string is too big and it doesn't fit in column. is there way to solve this?

**UPDATE**

the problem must be in sting size which is not fit in column. I tried to select less columns from joined tables, and it works properly. maybe there is way to convert my json column to text 'on fly' while select? I tried to cast the column to text like

```
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(...   AS TEXT)
```

but it gives syntax error

Comment: Is that a snapshot from PHPMyAdmin? it has a limit for field length to display, and when exceeded the data is cut, although MySQL is retrieving the full data. Editing the row shuold show the complete data.
If not, try checking the results directly in MySQL data engine.

Comment: yes, but it has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin. I dumped and also logged the result, its not proper JSON

Comment: So, add the not proper JSON into your question so we can see what it is wrong with it, preferably the one you dumped. And please do not use this archaic join syntax. Use proper INNER|LEFT|RIGHT JOIN syntax.

Comment: My wild guess is that it is something to do with some non ansi character on that database columns...

Comment: did you read the question ? I indicated the version, I also add the print screen of JSON, it has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin, I got the same result in logs

Comment: but why non ansi character should be a problem? all columns are in `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation, I guess the problem is that size of result string is too big

Comment: See: [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

Comment: thank you Paul! I knew that problem was with string length, I increased the size of `group_concat_max_len` and now it works) please, write your comment as answer and add some explanations, I will select it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was because of limited string length of `GROUP_CONCAT` function, which is 1024, thanks to @Paul Spiegel who mentioned this in comments sections. the length can be easily increased, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length) explains it clearly